# The Value of variable is going to negative value when performing some operation along with left Shift Operator in Java

Tags: java

```
public class Sample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        byte[] _temp1 = new byte[4];
        byte[] _temp2 = new byte[4];
        for(int i=0;i<_temp1.length; i++){
            _temp1[i/8] |= (1<<(7-(i%8)));
            System.out.println("Binary representation of _temp1["+(i/8)+"] is "+ Integer.toBinaryString(_temp1[i/8])+"decimal representation of temp1 is "+_temp1[i/8]);
            _temp2[i/8] |=(1<<(i%8));
            System.out.println("Binary representation of _temp2["+(i/8)+"] is "+ Integer.toBinaryString(_temp2[i/8])+"decimal representation of temp2 is "+_temp2[i/8]);

        }
    }   
}
```

This is  the code i am just using for reading a byte code from left to right i.e values are like `1,2,4,8,16,32,64,128 (_temp1[i/8] |= (1<<(7-(i%8)));)`
and from right to left that's general way of representation of binary code i.e,
values are like `128,64,32,16,8,4,2,1 (_temp2[i/8] |= (1<<((i%8)));)`

but, when I executed the above code the value that i am getting very different for first type the values are going to negatives when i  converted them to decimals but next representation is showing normally .

Output:

```
Binary representation of _temp1[0] is 11111111111111111111111110000000decimal representation of temp1 is -128
Binary representation of _temp2[0] is 1decimal representation of temp2 is 1
Binary representation of _temp1[0] is 11111111111111111111111111000000decimal representation of temp1 is -64
Binary representation of _temp2[0] is 11decimal representation of temp2 is 3
Binary representation of _temp1[0] is 11111111111111111111111111100000decimal representation of temp1 is -32
Binary representation of _temp2[0] is 111decimal representation of temp2 is 7
Binary representation of _temp1[0] is 11111111111111111111111111110000decimal representation of temp1 is -16
Binary representation of _temp2[0] is 1111decimal representation of temp2 is 15
```

please explain why it is showing differently..Thanks for your time and valuable comments

Comment: You do understand that `1 << 7` is `0x80`, and that bytes are signed in Java?

Comment: please be specific i didn't understand what is your meaning here see if i directly write a line of code to execute 1<<7 then is getting printed as 0x80 not going to show -128 in decimal but when the above program is executed it is showing negative values

Comment: I have been perfectly specific. I have asked you whether you understand two specific facts. Clearly you don't.

Comment: @MohithP Quote formatting is for quotes. The text you reformatted was computer output and should have been left alone.

Comment: Thanks EJP i've got it late what you meant...i've understood

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 in binary is 00000001. So 1 << 7 is 10000000 ( = - 128)

_temp1[i/8] |= (1<<(7-(i%8)));

case i = 0: 0/8 = 0 
=> _temp1[0] |= 1 << 7 
<=> _temp1[0] = _temp1[0] | 10000000  
_temp1[0] default = 0 => _temp1[0] = 00000000 | 10000000 ( = 10000000) 
case i = 1: 1/8 = 0 => _temp1[0] |= 1 << 6 
<=> _temp1[0] = 10000000 | 01000000 ( = 11000000  <=> -64 in decimal ) 
case i = 2: 2/8 = 0 => _temp[0] |= 1 << 5 
<=> _temp[0] = 11000000 | 00100000 ( = 11100000 <=> -32 in decimal)

Solution: change _temp1[i/8] to _temp1[i % 8]
and because max value of byte is 127, so if u wanna print 128:
change

byte[] _temp1 = new byte[4]

to

int[] _temp1 = new int[4]